# java json controller

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have an Java class, like Library, that contains many fields. I want do ajax call to server 
and in controller's method I want to have partly initialized @RequestBody Library with only
fields, which are present in json object.

I read the http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/, but I need not full object.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` (part of the [Jettison project](http://jettison.codehaus.org/)) and only include the fields that you need.
Or, you could just make a simplified version of `Library` that includes only the fields that you want (call it `AjaxLibrary` or something).

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a problem to use full object, cause fields would not be initialized, if they are not present at entire json.

Also you can create own [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class, e.g. `SomeActionLibraryDTO`. Extract required fields from Library, and use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation for class to ignore the rest of json object (I suppose you are using the default json jackson marshaller, right?)